# Batch Program to Start Windows Audio in Safe Mode

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command-prompt, safe-mode

This is the code:

```
@echo off

cls
echo.
echo Hello, %username%.
echo This program will enable the sound service.
echo.

:case_1
call:print "Attempting to start Windows Audio..."
call:check_audio "sc start AudioSrv" "case_2"

:case_2
call:print "Attempting to start Windows Audio again..."
call:check_audio "C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted" "case_3"

:case_3
echo.
echo Attempting to start dependencies...
echo.
call:print "Starting Multimedia Class Scheduler..."
call:check_active "MMCSS" "sc start MMCSS" "case_4" "Multimedia Class Scheduler"
call:print "Starting Remote Procedure Call (RPC)..."
call:check_active "RpcSs" "sc start RpcSs" "case_4" "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)"
call:print "Starting Windows Audio Endpoint Builder..."
call:check_active "AudioEndpointBuilder" "sc start AudioEndpointBuilder" "case_4" "Windows Audio Endpoint Builder"

call:print "Attempting to start Windows Audio again..."
call:check_audio "sc start AudioSrv" "case_4"

:case_4
echo.
echo Attempting to start dependencies again...
echo.
call:print "Starting Multimedia Class Scheduler..."
call:check_active "MMCSS" "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs" "error" "Multimedia Class Scheduler"
call:print "Starting Remote Procedure Call (RPC)..."
call:check_active "RpcSs" "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k rpcss" "error" "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)"
call:print "Starting Windows Audio Endpoint Builder..."
call:check_active "AudioEndpointBuilder" "C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted" "error" "Windows Audio Endpoint Builder"

call:print "Attempting to start Windows Audio again..."
call:check_audio "C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted" "error"

:print
echo %1
echo.

:check_audio
:: Checking if Windows Audio is active. If it is unable to be activated, GOTO <label>.
:: If it has already been activated, GOTO exit.
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "AudioSrv" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
    :: Tokenises line containing service's state, pulls out third token.
    :: Tests resulting state against the string, "RUNNING".
    if /i "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
        %1 || goto %2
    ) else (
        goto exit
    )
)

:check_active
:: Checking if service is active. If it is unable to be activated, GOTO <label>.
:: If it has already been activated, state that it is already running.
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "%1" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
    if /i "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
        %2 || goto %3
    ) else (
        echo %4 is already running.
    )
)

:error
:: States what error the program failed with and exits.
echo Program failed with error #%errorlevel%.
exit /b %errorlevel%

:exit
call:print "The program was successful. Windows Audio is running."
pause
exit
```

A little bit spaghetti-ish, but does the job... Sort of.
When I run it in normal mode, it just goes in an infinite loop, constantly calling the label ":exit" until I CTRL-C out of it. Why is this?

Comment: Did you consider renaming your label to something other than `exit`, like `quit` or `done`, to see if that would resolve the issue? (Or simply removing the final `exit` completely?) It's a little foolish to use a meaningful batch term as a label?

Comment: @KenWhite It is still producing an infinite loop:

    Hello, Michael.
    This program will enable the sound service.

    "Attempting to start Windows Audio..."

    The system cannot find the drive specified.
    "The program was successful. Windows Audio is running."

    The system cannot find the drive specified.
    "The program was successful. Windows Audio is running."

    The system cannot find the drive specified.
    "The program was successful. Windows Audio is running."

    The system cannot find the drive specified.
    "The program was successful. Windows Audio is running."

Comment: Removing the comments in the for loop of check_audio got rid of the "system cannot find" message, but still an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have calls that are falling through, and calls that are moving up and down in the call chain.

Here's a very simple example that will demonstrate the issue (you'll need to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to break out of the infinite loop (it may take several tries!) - check the output on the screen to see what happened):

```
@echo off
:callit
call:print "Callit"

:print                              :: Start execution
echo %1
echo.                               :: Fall through to :error

:error                              
echo "In Error"                     :: Continue execution (fall through)

:exit
call:print "Loop from exit"         :: Loop back upward to :print and start again
pause
exit
```

You'll see output similar to (small excerpt, start and end of run - large chunk of repetition in middle snipped for brevity):

```
"Callit"

"In Error"
"Loop from exit"

"In Error"
"Loop from exit"

"In Error"
"Loop from exit"

"In Error"
"Loop from exit"

"In Error"
"Loop from exit"

"In Error"
"Loop from exit"

"In Error"
"Loop from exit"

"In Error"
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
```